# Compress large file in ruby with Zlib for gzip

Tags: ruby, gzip, zlib

I have a very large file, approx. 200 million rows of data.

I would like to compress it with the Zlib library, specifically using the Writer.

Reading through each line one at at time seems like it would take quite a bit of time. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Here is what I have right now:

```
require 'zlib'

Zlib::GzipWriter.open('compressed_file.gz') do |gz|
 File.open(large_data_file).each do |line|
   gz.write line
 end
 gz.close
end
```

Comment: Reading line-by-line using `foreach` or `each` vs. slurping it via `read` is preferable, especially when the file is big. Slurping is not scalable. Instead of using Ruby and Zlib, why not let gzip handle the entire task? It'll be running in compiled code, not an interpreted script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use IO#read to read a chunk of arbitrary length from the file.

```
require 'zlib'

Zlib::GzipWriter.open('compressed_file.gz') do |gz|
 File.open(large_data_file) do |fp|
   while chunk = fp.read(16 * 1024) do
     gz.write chunk
   end
 end
 gz.close
end
```

This will read the source file in 16kb chunks and add each compressed chunk to the output stream. Adjust the block size to your preference based on your environment.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, is my code correct? I am trying to compress a tsv file, but whenever I run the code I posted it doesn't see to be compressing the data.

Comment: It looks right to me. You're saying that the output file contains the original data, uncompressed, or that the output file isn't created?

Comment: The output file contains the original data uncompressed. :-(

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing locally, too. Very odd - I don't have an immediate answer.

Comment: I think I know the answer. The newest version of vim decompresses/inflates the file automatically.

Comment: ...hahahah. Yes, I was looking at it with vim, too. Good catch.

Comment: As explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16904810/250703), I think it would be better to use 'rb' mode when reading the input file. `File.open(large_data_file, 'rb')`

Comment: even if vim was inflating the data, the size of the file remains same after compressing using this code.