# Compress file in Ruby - System vs Zlib?

Tags: ruby, gzip, zlib

I have a file in tune of few hundred MBs to be compressed. I don't need to go through that file per se, so I am free to use either `system` or use `Zlib` like explained [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496799/compress-large-file-in-ruby-with-zlib-for-gzip).

I am inclined towards `system` because my ruby process doesn't have to bother reading it and bloating up, so use well known gzip command to run through system. Also, I get the exit status, so I know how it went.

Anything I am missing? Is there a best practice around this? Any loopholes?

Comment: Yes, as you have the problem described, the best solution would be to delegate it to system `gzip`. Please note, that if you expect the consumer to be on windows, `zip` would be probably a better choice. Otherwise I would consider checking `bzip2` since it provides a better compression compared to `gzip`.

Comment: Not windows - Linux/OSX. Thanks for suggestion on bzip2, will take a look. If `system` is better, then we'll have a plethora of tools suddenly available :)

Comment: Just be careful to use the multi-argument form of [`Kernel#system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-system) so that you don't have to worry about quoting everything for the shell.

Answer (score 1):

If you will use `system` command than you can't intervene in compression. So you won't be able to redirect compressed output to socket, provide external progress bar, combine custom tar archive etc. These things may be important during compression of large files.

Please look at the following example using [ruby-zstds](https://github.com/andrew-aladev/ruby-zstds) (zstd is better than gzip today).

```rb
require "socket"
require "zstds"
require "minitar"

TCPSocket.open "google.com", 80 do |socket|
  writer = ZSTDS::Stream::Writer.new socket

  begin
    Minitar::Writer.open writer do |tar|
      tar.add_file_simple "file.txt" do |tar_writer|
        File.open "file.txt", "r" do |file|
          tar_writer.write(file.read(512)) until file.eof?
        end
      end
      tar.add_file_simple "file2.txt" ...
    end
  ensure
    writer.close
  end
end
```

We are reading `file.txt` in a streaming way, adding it to tar archive and sending portions to google immediately. We don't need to store any compressed files.